# Woocommerce - update total price if quantity is being typed in quantity field

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I can't get my get wrap my head around one problem and I also could not find any solution on the internets.

I have a function that on products page displays total price - quantity multiplied by products price:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_total_product_price', 31 );
function woocommerce_total_product_price() {
    global $woocommerce, $product;
    // let's setup our divs
    echo sprintf('<div id="product_total_price" style="margin-bottom:20px;">%s %s</div>',__('','woocommerce'),'<span class="price">'.$product->get_price().'</span>');
    ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(function($){
                var price = <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>,
                    currency = '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';

                $('[name=quantity]').change(function(){
                    if (!(this.value < 1)) {

                        var product_total = parseFloat(price * this.value);

                        $('#product_total_price .price').html( product_total.toFixed(0) + currency);

                    }
                });
            });
```

and then another one that I use to create a button that will update quantity field input a on button click:

```
    jQuery( function($) {
    $('#quantity4').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('[name="quantity"]').val('4');
        console.log('#quantity4 was clicked');
    });
});
```

The problem is that whenever I use the function of second code I mentioned the input field does change to given number but the total price from the first code snippet doesn't update right away - it does only when I click the increment buttons.

Same things happen when I type in a value in quantity field manually - I still have to click increment button for total price to update.

I don't really know what is the problem in this case and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Setting a field value _via script_, does not fire the `change` event. You will have to trigger the event yourself in this instance, using https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Basically, `$('[name="quantity"]').val('4').trigger('change');` should do the trick.